# i want to change the text color based on the condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show the text color change dynamically based on the condition that i am using in the code.Below is the code that i am using.Please help me out from this problem.

```
<span class="pendtext" style="font-size:15px;">{{($duepay->status == 'issued') ? 'PENDING' : (($duepay->status == 'paid') ? 'SUCCESSFUL' : $duepay->status)}}</span>


<script>

if($duepay->status == 'issued'){
  $(".pendtext").css('color','green');
}
else{
  $(".pendtext").css('color','yellow');
}

</script>
```

Comment: is this a twig template? just set a defined css class with green and yellow, then add that into that class with a ternary on the tag attribute, then you eliminate the need to do this in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a JS if you work with PHP? you can do with PHP too like

```
<span class="pendtext" style="font-size:15px;color:{{($duepay->status == 'issued')?'green':'yellow'}}">{{($duepay->status == 'issued') ? 'PENDING' : (($duepay->status == 'paid') ? 'SUCCESSFUL' : $duepay->status)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$duepay->status` is presumably coming from your PHP code so you need to output it in the JS in the same way you have in the HTML:

```
if ('{{$duepay->status}}' === 'issued'){
  $(".pendtext").css('color', 'green');
}
else{
  $(".pendtext").css('color', 'yellow');
}
```

Note that this can be shortened using a ternary expression:

```
$(".pendtext").css('color', '{{$duepay->status}}' === 'issued' ? 'green' : 'yellow');
```

Or to keep the logic entirely in the PHP:

```
$(".pendtext").css('color', '{{$duepay->status == 'issued' ? 'green' : 'yellow'}});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but the else part color is not changing both text are showing in same green color

Comment: Have you checked the exact output of `$duepay->status` in those cases? Ensure there's no whitespace around the value

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this :

```
    <div id="pend" class="pendtext" style="font-size:15px;">

    </div>

    <script>

    if ('{{$duepay->status}}' === 'issued'){
    document.getElementById('pend').innerHTML = "<p>PENDING</p>";
    document.getElementById('pend').style='color:green';
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('pend').innerHTML = "<p>SUCCESSFUL</p>";
    document.getElementById('pend').style='color:yellow';
    }

    </script>
```